# A question on proving an equation to be an $n$-linear system in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

While studying Determinants from text book Hoffman and Kunze, I have a in an argument in a theorem whose reasoning is not provided .

Questions:
1st question is in underlined part of theorem.

It's image :

[image]

> How did authors deduced that $A_{ij} D_{ij}(A) $ is n-linear function of A?

Question 2:  How does author derived the last line which is "Therefore $ E_{j} (A) $ = $(-1)^{k+j} $ .... .

Can anyone please give some hints.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, look that $D_{ij}(A)$ does not depend on the i-th row of its argument (without loss of generality since  D is [n-1] - linear) then $D_{ij}(\lambda A + B)) = \lambda^{n-1} D_{ij} A + D_{ij} B$ look that $D_{ij} (\cdot)$ just ignores the i-th rows of $A$ and $B$ and operates linearly on the rest. Since $A_{ij}$ doesn't get affected by $D_{ij}$, because it's in the i-th row, we can just multiply it with $D_{ij}(A)$ and we preserve the linear relationship with $A$, just write down the adecuate expresión for $\lambda A_{ij} D_{ij}(\lambda A)$ and you'll get that $A_{ij} D_{ij} (A)$ is in fact n-linear in A.

For the second one we assumed that the rows $\alpha_k = \alpha_{k+1}$ and that $D$ is alternating, which means that any (n-1)-matrix containing the rows $\alpha_k$, $\alpha_{k+1}$ will yield 0 in being operated by $D$. Those matrices are sub-matrices $A(i|j)$ of $A$ where $i \neq k$ and $i \neq k+1$. Observe that $j$ can be any column. This tell us that in the definition of $E$ (the sum over the rows), all terms not deleting the row $k$ nor $k+1$ must be zero (again since D is alternating). Therefore, we have only 2 terms left in our sumation, namely:
$$
(-1)^{k+i} A_{k j} D_{k j}(A)+(-1)^{k+1+i} A_{(k+1) j} D_{(k+1) j}(A)
$$

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

At here, $D_{ij}A_{ij}$ should be interpreted as a function $f_i:M_{n\times n}(F)\to F$, $f_i(A)=A_{ij}D_{ij}(A)$.
$$f_i
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1\\ 
r_2\\ 
\vdots\\ 
v+\lambda w \\
\vdots\\ 
r_n
\end{pmatrix}
=(v_i+\lambda w_i)
D
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1'\\ 
r_2'\\ 
\vdots\\  
r_n'
\end{pmatrix}
=v_i
D\begin{pmatrix}
r_1'\\ 
r_2'\\ 
\vdots\\  
r_n'
\end{pmatrix}
+\lambda w_i
D\begin{pmatrix}
r_1'\\ 
r_2'\\ 
\vdots\\  
r_n'
\end{pmatrix}
=f_i
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1\\ 
r_2\\ 
\vdots\\ 
v\\
\vdots\\ 
r_n
\end{pmatrix}
+
\lambda f_i
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1\\ 
r_2\\ 
\vdots\\ 
w \\
\vdots\\ 
r_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
That is, $f_i$ is $n$-linear.